# Unable to update record prior to deletion

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In one of my application services, I am trying to update a record prior to deleting (with soft delete).
After playing around, i find that i can either update the record or delete it, but i cant do both. the last operation (in this case delete) always takes precedence.

If i delete and then update, the record is not marked as deleted and the column updates, so how can i update the records `url` and `displayname` prior to deleting? I added the `UnitOfWork` attribute, but it didnt seem to have any affect

My method can be found below.

```
    [AbpAuthorize(AppPermissions.Pages_PmnyDocuments_Delete)]
    [UnitOfWork]
    public async Task Delete(EntityDto input)
    {
        var entity = await _pmnyDocumentsRepository.GetAsync(input.Id);
        var output = await _fileServerManager.DeleteAsync(new DeleteFileServerObjectInput(PmnyConsts.Bucket, $"{entity.MasterId}/{entity.ParentIdentifier}".AsFilePath(), entity.DisplayName));
        entity.Url = output.FilePath;
        entity.DisplayName = output.FileName;
        await _pmnyDocumentsRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);

        var entity2 = await _pmnyDocumentsRepository.GetAsync(entity.Id);
        await _pmnyDocumentsRepository.DeleteAsync(entity2.Id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try removing the `[UnitOfWork]` attribute and instead wrapping the update & delete in their own uow.

```
 using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
 {
          //UPDATE
 }

 using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
 {
          //DELETE
 }
```

There is further info in the documentation [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work?searchKey=unit%20of%20work%20asp.net%20boilerplate)

Answer (score -1):

you need to issue a save changes between the two calls , because all commits to the database automaticly happens at the end of your method.

see this quote

> SaveChanges
>   ASP.NET Boilerplate saves all changes at the end of a unit of work. You don't have to do anything, but sometimes you may want to save changes to the database in the middle of a unit of work operation. For example, after saving some changes, we may want to get the Id of a newly inserted Entity using EntityFramework.
>
> You can use the SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync method of the current
>   unit of work.
>
> Note that if the current unit of work is transactional, all changes in
>   the transaction are rolled back if an exception occurs. Even the saved
>   changes!